# How to create a Clickhouse materialized view of TOP N most frequent values

Tags: clickhouse, materialized-views

I have a huge table of DNS requests and would like to report on the most frequent domains queried over time. eg top 20 domains requested each 5 minutes over a year.

A traditional SQL query could GROUP BY/count()/ORDER BY/LIMIT BY. But I ingest billions of rows per month and can only keep the source data for a few days. I would like to create a Materialised View to keep the report data over time. Perhaps a SummingMergeTree.

```
toStartOfHour(Timestamp), domain, count
```

But I only want to keep the most frequent (not the thens of millions of other domains in 5 min chunks). How in the materialised view SELECT can I roll up only the most frequent domains? As I understand it, the select is only run on each block of INSERTS, which may not have the same frequency as the overall data.

This seems like it should be an easy thing to do. Am I missing something obvious?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This seems like it should be an easy thing to do.

Except it's impossible.

I would use SELECT over pre-aggregated Mat.Vie + cron / per hour -> dashboard_results_table

Comment: Thank you Denny. I appreciate your help again.